# There is any example/studies/concepts on really short blade jet turbines/turboshafts?

Tags: turbine, blade, turboshaft

Well, from the little I know, I **think** the reason jet turbines can't go that fast is because the tip of the blades would reach supersonic speeds and starting to generate too much drag.

However, if, for some reason, the engineer intention is to make a jet turbine/turboshaft to spin really really fast instead of generating thrust (for whatever reason), it would be practical, for example, alongate the length of the turbine and also decreasing the size of its inner blades?

Or if your intention is to just spin really fast, you should just use gear boxes?

I ask that because there could be some applications, like maybe allow for a Ornithopter, perhaps? Just curious.

Comment: This ask, or that. Not all ask you. -yoda

Comment: Yes there are fast engines [around 1 million rpm](https://www.celeroton.com/fileadmin/user_upload/technologie/publications/IEEE_Publication_Megaspeed.pdf), not necessarily turbomachines. It turns out this one was built by a spin-off of the University of Zurich. Switzerland is better known for its cuckoos than for its ornithopters though.

Comment: The problem is that the engines are as big as they are to get the mass flow rate through them. Smaller engines do spin faster, but they have less power too.

Comment: @JanHudec "*Smaller engines do spin faster, but they have less power too*", for the same quantity of fuel. We can get the same power by increasing air acceleration instead of air mass, but not with the same fuel rate O(N²) vs O(N).

Comment: How does spinning really fast relate to ornithopter application?  If you wanted to build a turbomachinery powered ornithoper, existing turboshaft engines (i.e. helicopter engines) should be fine, without changing anything about their spin rate.